# How to pass Secrets without hard-coding in cloud formation template/blueprint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

We are having some secrets(external secrets), Not something which is return from cloud formation templates. In that case, we have to  pass that secrets in the cloud formation template/blueprint.

Is there any alternative rather than giving hardcoded secrets inside the CFN blueprint/template.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html):

> When you use a dynamic reference, CloudFormation retrieves the value of the specified reference when necessary **during stack and change set operations**.

You could store your secrets in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store  or AWS Secrets Manager, and the dynamic reference could retrieve them without needing to hard-code their actual values in the templates.

Comment: Actually we don't want to do it manually to store secrets in secrets manager. Is there any other solution. Like, can we collect all secrets in a file and then that file can be upload to the s3 bucket. Through s3 bucket can we update secrets to secrets manager ? Is that possible.

Comment: @PrashanthKanuka Yes, but this is something that you have construct yourself. There is no out-of-the-box mechanism for that in AWS.

Comment: I second the suggestion to store the secret/sensitive data in SSM/PS and just pass the name of the parameters around.  Then the code can lookup the values when it needs them.  Just make sure to cache the values in code, meaning don't call make parameter store calls every time the code wants to reference the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the secrets in S3 and can provide that path in the AWS Secrets. In the CF template, you are not passing the secrets directly then.